# How to rotate a group of 2D layers around the midpoint in one axis only?

Tags: after-effects

I have lots of point light layers aligned as a vertical line.

Now I'd like to distribute the 2D-light-layers along an ellipse into the 3D space (probably the z-axis).

How could I do this, without having to pic each of the (200) lights manually? How can I eg select the first few lights and rotate them based on the most left light into the z-axis? You know, so that the first light stays at this position, but all the others are moved into the back a bit.

I could then repeat it with several bunch of lights so this could give me an approximated ellipse. But how can I set some kind of "rotation point" if I select multiple layers and want to rotate them?

Comment: Maybe a little drawing or image would help to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. Guessing from what you are saying you would have to move the anchor point and maybe work with a null object.